# How many guards watch the slave pen in "Out of the Abyss"?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, out-of-the-abyss

This is my first time DMing and the campaign we are playing *Out of the Abyss*. In chapter 1, the wording is kind of confusing, where it says in the ["What the Prisoners Know"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/oota/prisoners-of-the-drow#WhatthePrisonersKnow) section (p. 8) that

> the slaves know that the slave pen is overlooked by three guards. When I looked at where the book places the guards, I imagine one to be watching over the slaves, and then two in the guard tower… not able to see the slaves. Does that mean that there is only one guard watching the pen?

Please help me understand the guard layout! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

From the description, it sounds as if there are

> three guards stationed in the tower across the bridge.  It explicitly states that the guards are far and distracted, so the players can get away with doing things unseen.

You can feel free to add your own guard patrols, but

> the description does not mention a guard positioned outside the cell.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response! Basically what I did was one guard directly outside the pen watching over the slaves, kind of still understanding that guards can be on the outside of the stalagtites.

Comment: Bronsola, you can accept his response by clicking the check mark next to his answer. :) Also, it's me.